# How do I implement postMessage() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I need help with the `window.postMessage` method. I'm trying to post a message to an iframe from the parent window.

The iframe's name and ID is `myFrame`, and I have tried the following code, with no avail:

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.postMessage('Hello','*')
```

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain? Otherwise you're going to be running into XSS security issues and quite likely the reason it's not working.

Comment: @kieran I was looking for a cross-domain communication and I found this as the best way after almost 2 days of googling :-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.postmessage

Comment: What error did it give you? Just "it's not working" is not specific enough.

Comment: @Thai no error is being produced in the console, it's left blank!!

Comment: A bit OT, but there are some very good ways of doing cross domain/frame communication that doesn't use window.postmessage, try to look here for inspiration: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: @Martin thanks for the info. actually I was not looking for using AJAX at all, but it seems to be I got no other choice.

Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a step back and debug.

1. What does `document.getElementById('myIframe')` give you?
2. What does `document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow` give you?
3. Do you have a global method named `postMessage` in the iframe?
4. Is the iframe domain the same as the initial page? **It has to be.**
5. Does the browser throw any errors in the console?

Comment: The iframe *does not* have to be on the same domain for window.postMessage.

Comment: Mattio is correct, the iframe does not have to be on the same domain. I've run into this problem as well and it seems the problem lies in that document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow returns undefined.